# Disable onClick for DatePicker in Popover

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, popover

I have a issue where I have popover being displayed inside the popover I am providing a datepicker where user can select a date and perform some action.
But when the user clicks on datepicker it expands out of the popover and once the user selects any date it hides the popover.
I do want to hide the popover on any click outside the popover but not when the date is being selected, I did try stopPropogation, preventDefault but that didnt help.

Below is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdyico?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts
Once you click on Should Mimic this button you should see the popover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the ngbDatepicker node inside the popover node with [autoClose]="'outside'" and it will not close on click.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `autoClose` to `false` or `'outside'`

Here is your code updated
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qurywt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

more info on popover API  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api

Comment: The issue with autoClose 'outside' is that if the calendar is opened to select a date and if you click outside the popover to select the date that closes the popover

Comment: you can set it to `false` and pragmatically close popover with `.close()`  of popover